# Como situar una tabla debajo de otra tabla?

Tags: html, css, table

Estoy teniendo problemas al situar una tabla debajo de otra, las tablas son la siguientes:

Quisiera situar la tabla **SALDOS SIGUIENTES** debajo de **SALDOS**

Para la creación de la tabla tengo el siguiente codigo:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  
  div#tablas_saldos {
    display: block;
}

div.saldos {
    display: block;
}

.subtitulo {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
}

.table {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

span#eliminar-saldo-btn {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: #ab1313;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
    padding: 2px;
}

.table>tbody>tr>td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#saldo_dias1 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#saldo_dias {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

td.saldossiguientes {
    display: block;
}

div.saldosAnticipados {
    display: block;
}
  
}
```

```html
<div id="tablas_saldos">
<div>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="saldosTabla">
    <h3 class="subtitulo">
    SALDOS
    </h3>
    <div class="saldos">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Año</th>
        <th>Saldo</th>
        <th>Fecha vencimiento</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span id="eliminar-saldo-btn" title="Eliminar" style="display: none">x</span>
        </td>
        <td data-title="Año">2020</td>
        <td data-title="Saldo">6</td>
        <td data-title="Fecha vencimiento">22/04/2022</td>
        <td rowspan="1" id="saldodias1">6</td>
        <td rowspan="1" id="saldodias" style="display: none">6</td>
        <td rowspan="1" id="ValidarDias" style="display: none">0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="saldossiguientes">
      <h3 class="subtitulo">
      SALDOS SIGUIENTES
      </h3>
      <div class="saldosAnticipados">
      <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Año sig.</th>
          <th>Dias por asignar</th>
          <th>Dias anticipados</th>
          <th>total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span id="eliminar-saldo-btn" title="Eliminar" style="display: none">x</span>
          </td>
          <td data-title="AnioSiguiente">2021</td>
          <td data-title="DiasOtorgados">10</td>
          <td data-title="SaldosAdelantados">0</td>
          <td data-title="total" id="saldo_adelantado">10</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Es importante resaltar que estoy haciendo uso de `media-queries`, cuando la pantalla sea mayor a
`425px` pues la tabla no deberá verse afectada y permanecerá una al lado de otra.

Comment: ¿No sería mucho mas sencillo que saldos fuera realmente una tabla independiente de saldos siguientes?, dado lo que expones parece que tendría mas sentido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contemplando que actualizaste la pregunta e indicas que hay que respetar el `media query` lo ideal puede ser usar 2 `div` que contengan a cada `tabla` y emplear la propiedad css `float`; por lo tanto es necesario tocar el CSS

**quedaría se la siguiente forma y este seria el Ejemplo**

```css
.saldos {
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  
  .saldos {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }

    .subtitulo {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: medium;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .table {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    span#eliminar-saldo-btn {
        display: block;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        font-family: cursive;
        color: #ab1313;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
        padding: 2px;
    }

    .table>tbody>tr>td {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #saldo_dias1 {
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #saldo_dias {
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }  
}
```

```html
<div id="tablas_saldos">
    <div class="saldos">
        <h3 class="subtitulo">SALDOS</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Año</th>
                    <th>Saldo</th>
                    <th>Fecha vencimiento</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><span id="eliminar-saldo-btn" title="Eliminar" style="display: none">x</span></td>
                    <td data-title="Año">2020</td>
                    <td data-title="Saldo">6</td>
                    <td data-title="Fecha vencimiento">22/04/2022</td>
                    <td rowspan="1" id="saldodias1">6</td>
                    <td rowspan="1" id="saldodias" style="display: none">6</td>
                    <td rowspan="1" id="ValidarDias" style="display: none">0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>
  <div class="saldos">
        <h3 class="subtitulo">SALDOS SIGUIENTES</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Año sig.</th>
                    <th>Dias por asignar</th>
                    <th>Dias anticipados</th>
                    <th>total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><span id="eliminar-saldo-btn" title="Eliminar" style="display: none">x</span></td>
                    <td data-title="AnioSiguiente">2021</td>
                    <td data-title="DiasOtorgados">10</td>
                    <td data-title="SaldosAdelantados">0</td>
                    <td data-title="total" id="saldo_adelantado">10</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

te dejo un link al video de la prueba: https://youtu.be/RSLBTEaqeDo

Comment: No encuentro las clases `saldosTabla`, `saldosAnticipados`, `saldossiguientes` que originalmente estan en mi pregunta, esto me confunde un poco.

Comment: no las necesitas...

Comment: a menos que las uses para otro proposito en javascript

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente el código indica que los dos (Saldos y Saldos siguientes) están en el mismo `tr`, en dos `td` distintos, uno al lado del otro, y lo muestra tal cual. Si lo quiere debajo pon "Saldos siguientes" en un `tr` nuevo.

Cambia

```
</td>
<td class="saldossiguientes">
```

Por

```
</td>
</tr>
<td>
<td class="saldossiguientes">
```

Comment: Esto afectara en algo al momento de verse desde una resolución mayor a `425px` ?

Answer (score 0):

mediante css podés dividir la tabla por div. colócale una clase y usa flexbox, usa display: Flex
flex-direction: column

todo mediante css y deben estar dentro de una caja padre a la cual le colocas esos atributos

Comment: Puedes aportarme un ejemplo con el código puesto a mi pregunta para darle validez a tu respuesta